# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to count this `$maxjam` variable in this code

```
$my_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
shuffle($my_array);

foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
$hari = $my_array[$key];
if($hari == 5){

    $maxjam = 6;
}elseif ($hari == 6){

    $maxjam = 8;

}else{  

    $maxjam = 7;

}

$jumlahjam = count($maxjam);
print_r($jumlahjam);
echo'<br>';
}
```

But i get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable
>
> Filename: controllers/jadwal.php
>
> Line Number: 166

How to solve this error?

Comment: Do `var_dump` of $maxjam. What does it show? As the error suggests `$maxjam` isn't an array or a countable object so you cannot use `count` on it.

Comment: Wait, no need for the `var_dump`, you are clearly defining `$maxjam` as an integer, so why are you trying to count it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why count it at all? `echo $maxjam;` looks like all you want

Comment: `$maxjam` is an int, not an array or object so you can't count it...

Comment: @Script47 i want to know the sum of this $maxjam to compare it with another variable

Comment: Then use an `if` statement? It is already an int.

Comment: @Darren then how should i count them?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the whole script?

Comment: @Darren i want to sum this $maxjam variable, just to know the sum of this $maxjam

Comment: https://eval.in/1014471

Answer (score 3):

Try this out,This method replaces all the other methods.This is because you are using a new version,you should  return an array.IF YOU ARE USING CODEIGNITER ,Then just change the code as i have mentioned below

change your `if (count($chkAdminExist)):`
to   `if (count((array)$chkAdminExist)):`

ps:$chkAdminExist is my variable,this may differ from yours

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `$maxjam` variable to be an integer therefore the `count` function fails. If you want to create a new array and append an new element on every iteration, use `$maxjam[] = <value>`.

```
$my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
shuffle($my_array);
$maxjam = [];

foreach ($my_array as $hari) {
    if($hari == 5) {
        $maxjam[] = 6;
    } elseif ($hari == 6) {
        $maxjam[] = 8;
    } else {  
        $maxjam[] = 7;
    }

    $jumlahjam = count($maxjam);
    print_r($jumlahjam);
    echo'<br>';
}
```

Comment: You are assuming the OP's intended action and that is never a good way to answer a question.

Comment: Highly agree with @Script47 here. Assumption might kill your answer. Also, your answer is wrong, you're running the count inside the loop so it will occur each time....

Answer (score 0):

The count function use for an array or an object, the $maxjam is integer.
I'm using php 7.1 and in your code run well. but all is 1.
i think you want some it

```
$maxjam = 0;
foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
    $hari = $my_array[$key];
    if($hari == 5){    
        $maxjam+= 6;
    }elseif ($hari == 6){    
        $maxjam+= 8;    
    }else{      
        $maxjam+= 7;    
    }
}
echo $maxjam;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array type variable should be use for count function.

```
$my_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
shuffle($my_array);$maxjam=array();
foreach ($my_array as $key => $value){
    $hari = $my_array[$key];
    if($hari == 5){  
    array_push($maxjam,6);
    }elseif ($hari == 6){a
    rray_push($maxjam,8);
    }else{ 
    array_push($maxjam,7);
    }
}
$jumlahjam = count($maxjam);
print_r($jumlahjam);
echo'<br>';
```